# Как обновить часы по запросу новой временной зоны в корневом компоненте? react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, время, setinterval, redux

Пытаюсь обновлять часы в корневом компоненте. Общий вид приложения такой:

```
<App>
    <Input/>
    {timer}
</App>
```

Изначально из стора грузится дефолтный город, после устанавливаю начальное значение времени(setTime()):

```
componentWillMount() {
        const { setTime, timeOffset } = this.props;

        setTime(timeOffset);
    };
```

Затем, соответственно, запускаю setInterval, таймер для текущего города идёт, часы работают:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { setTime, timeOffset } = this.props;

        this.timer = setInterval(() => {
            setTime(timeOffset);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

После в  по сабмиту получаю координаты, нового введённого города, получаю свежую временную зону - всё асинхронно, props само собой меняются с задержкой. Как теперь перезапустить часы/таймер по setTime() с новым значением timeOffset, которое точно приходит в app.props? Пробовал отложенно перезапускать таймер, опробовал варианты, которые функции жизненного цикла предоставляют. Либо что-то недосмотрел - не дочитал, либо полностью надо логику таймера менять?

Comment: вы уже сделали все не правильно, у вас вычислительная логика в интерфейсе, её следует вынести в экшн. Экшн будет диспатчить событие, событие изменит глобальное состояние, состояние изменит данные в интерфейсе (это если использовать redux по назначению)

Comment: То есть часть с setInterval() также вынести в экшн? Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Ну создание и остановку таймера в экшн, да, и диспатчем в редьюсер отправляйте нужные вам параметры

Comment: Спасибо. Ткнули в нужную сторону. Нашёл примеры реализаций, буду разбирать.